# Some keys not working when I power up laptop

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I am using a Thinkpad R61i.

Some keys does not work properly when I power up my laptop; I have to hit with a hammer force so that it works.
But after a while everything is OK.

Is that related to something like warmup? What can I do?

Comment: The first attempt should be to open it up and unplug/replug the keyboard connectors.

Comment: @DanH it's a laptop, where is the connector?

Comment: Inside the laptop.  That's why you open it up.